# vim and macvim are not reading my .vim directory

Tags: macos, vim, macports, macvim

I have installed vim and macvim using macports, and tried copying over my .vim directory from linux. Neither seems to read anything from that directory: my customizations for folding and indenting aren't working, and :scriptnames shows only the system-wide /usr/share plugin directories are being read.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Macvim is not supposed to read anything from /usr/share I suggest you remove both vim and macvim installed via macports and instead install the latest macvim snapshot from the official downloads.

Comment: By `.vim` do you mean a subdirectory of your home directory, `~/.vim/`?  That should work.  Do you have a vimrc file, `~/.vimrc`?  Can you give a specific file that should be `source`d but is not?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to add the file I needed to the system vim file that MacVim created on installation. This file can be found using `:scriptnames` command.

I needed to use pathogen and it was not working placing it in my `.vim` file in the home directory. I placed the pathogen.vim in the system vim/autoload directory and then pathogen worked without errors.

I found the right directory in `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/autoload`